# problem running script to a remote machine

Tags: bash, ssh

I run a script via ssh to a remote machine :

```
ssh -p$port $user@$ip "bash /dati/bin/add_data.sh $t_ext_aria $t_pannello $t_ext_muro $t_cantina $t_bollitore $t_PT $t_P1 $t_P2 $H_PT $H_P1 $H_P2"
```

the content of the script add_data.sh ( in the remote machine)  is pretty self explanatory : run a mysql query passing 11 params:

```
query="INSERT INTO temp (t_ext_aria , t_pannello , t_ext_muro , t_cantina , t_bollitore , t_PT , t_P1 , t_P2 , H_PT , H_P1 , H_P2) VALUES ($1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,${10},${11})"
echo $query >> debug.log
mysql --user=rf --password=password tana << EOF
$query;
EOF
```

everything works fine except it doesn't log anything in debug.log ( I need to log to investigate why sometimes mysql query fails : probably some wrong formatted data )

BUT If I log in to the remote machine and I run the script from there:  e.g.

```
bash add_data.sh 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

it correctly write to debug.log .

I put permission 777 to avoid any issue .

where am  I wrong?

thank's fab

Comment: show `ls -al /dati/bin/add_data.sh` from the remote host. Also `echo $user` from the local host.

Comment: Your script writes debug.log to $user's home directory and not to /dati/bin/ when you run it via ssh.

Comment: thank's @cyrus , that's solve my problem (I fell a bit stupid !)